# Unable to change log level using Spring Boot Actuator

Tags: logging, spring-boot-actuator

I have two existing Spring Boot Applications with actuator endpoints enabled for loggers.

Both have Gradle rule and application.properties entries as below.

```
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator')
```

```
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=env,loggers
management.endpoint.loggers.enabled=true
```

But, when I try change log level as below it is working only for first app.

```
curl -s -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"configuredLevel": "debug"}' http://localhost:8080/actuator/loggers/com.zzz.yyy.ddd
```

I am not externalizing logger config files (i.e. they are in `src/main/resources` for both apps).
After some digging noticed that the first app is using `logback.xml` with SL4J logger, where as second app is using `log4j2-spring.xml` with `org.apache.logging.logger`. Could that be the reason and is it that we have to use logback/SL4J to make log level change with actuator endpoint work?

Comment: Looks like not an actuator issue, actuator endpoint allows to modify the logging level and probe of it shows the new level. But messages not logged based on newly updated log level (DEBUG). One more update logging level change and debug logging works fine thru IDE, problem is only when running as an executable jar. Tried providing `application.properties` file that works in IDE as an external resource, actuator/env shows it got picked up but still doesn't log debug messages when running as executable jar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My team lead helped identify the issue. `log4j2-spring.xml` had multiple file appenders with multiple custom levels, similar to listed below for various purpose like audit, backup, rejects etc.

```
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="WARN">
            <AppenderRef ref="Console" />
            <AppenderRef ref="defaultLogFile" level="info"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="MyAppAuditFile" level="auditLevel" />
            <AppenderRef ref="MyAppReplayFile" level="replayLevel" />
            <AppenderRef ref="MyAppBackupFile" level="backupLevel"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
```

As can be seen the default log file had log level set as info and hence only info and higher are going to that file, so when log level is changed to debug, those debug messages never went to log file. Where as Console didn't 've a log level setting resulting in debug messages to be displayed in IDE. So the fix was to just remove the `level` entry for default log fie just like Console.